# How to encode URLs in Dart?

Tags: http, url, flutter, dart, httprequest

I'm trying to port some code from Python to Dart (for a Flutter application). However, I'm having a bit of trouble encoding URLs. I'm trying to do the equivalent of `parsedData = urllib.parse.quote(STR_DATA)`. The closest I've gotten is with the Uri Dart class, with:

```
parsedData = Uri(queryParameters: STR_DATA);
parsedData = Uri.encodeComponent(parsedData.toString());
```

This gets close to what I'm trying to get but not quite. The result I get using Python is something like this (side note: it's only encoding after the period):

```
ig_sig_key_version=4&signed_body=efbcf4ac8577da5eb43f33f369cda4248dba52a407e88a565038b53933737bba.%7B%22phone_id%22%3A%20%22ee79227a-cf89-41c8-9598-d0c6f3931fa4%22%2C%20%22_csrftoken%22%3A%20%22BB1PRXVV1y6FgU0Rfmcda3jJG5eVFSPd%22%2C%20%22username%22%3A%20%22USERNAME%22%2C%20%22guid%22%3A%20%22c668814c-a1e9-487c-97f0-8491b2c07c1c%22%2C%20%22device_id%22%3A%20%22android-7eb57ab90e1e2c3e%22%2C%20%22password%22%3A%20%22PASSWORD%22%2C%20%22login_attempt_count%22%3A%20%220%22%7D
```

While with Dart, I get something like this:

```
ig_sig_key_version=4&signed_body=d1c26c132b536b3f4ffdd7f5c0524503e48216fb7f638b5f4cab65d74a9834de.%3Fphone_id%3D112626ab-1946-4ad0-bc63-b233f57033f9%26_csrftoken%3DhiPh0jSvjd0eP2dP4VUr83t3htYF7xci%26username%3DUSERNAME%26guid%3D999d2242-f52a-4044-96d9-2245c6757fbc%26device_id%3Dandroid-5daff5c3029f414c%26password%3DPASSWORD%26login_attempt_count%3D0
```

By the way, the reason why I need this to encode in the same way is because otherwise my HTTP request returns 400. Anyway, any help is appreciated; thank you in advance.

**OTHER SIDE NOTE: I think this is what's causing my request to be rejected but I don't know, I haven't done a lot of web stuff. If you think it might be something else, feel free to correct me.**

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247302/4712391

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are doing too much.
In this case, you *only* need to do: `parsedData = Uri.encodeComponent(STR_DATA);` to get the same result as the Python code.

Comment: Ok, so, I think the encoding mightn't be my problem after all. Do you have any idea why my request might be getting rejected? Some more info: it's a post request, the headers are the same, the bodies are those (in each language), that's why I thought it was that, because it's the only thing that's different but I'll keep trying to figure it out. Thanks for your answer and any other recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Ok, update, when I copy the body generated by python, the request goes through, so it's definitely that.

Answer (score 27):

Use Dart Uri Class

```
var uri = 'http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret john';
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(uri);
assert(encoded == 'http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret%20john');

var decoded = Uri.decodeFull(encoded);
assert(uri == decoded);
```

Comment: Ok, so, I think the encoding mightn't be my problem after all. Do you have any idea why my request might be getting rejected? Some more info: it's a post request, the headers are the same, the bodies are those (in each language), that's why I thought it was that, because it's the only thing that's different but I'll keep trying to figure it out. Thanks for your answer and any other recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Ok, update, when I copy the body generated by python, the request goes through, so it's definitely that.

Comment: Getting error - Illegal percent encoding in URI

Comment: @krishnadas Krishnadas - Kindly check this topic and share your suggestion, Thanks a lot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345632/how-to-decode-url-in-dart-flutter

Comment: thanks bro for sharing this code :)