# How to decode URL in dart / flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, urldecode

I have below link with a message in my database:

```
Please use this link to see Ferret John profile <a href="http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret%20john" target="_blank">http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret%20john</a> and like it.
```

I want to show following message as output in my flutter application:

```
Please use this link to see Ferret John profile <a href="http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret john" target="_blank">http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret john</a> and like it.
```

Kindly suggest how can I decode URL as above mentioned with message in Dart / Flutter? Thanks

Comment: needs more clarity what output you are expecting, and where do you want the output.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe Thanks for your response. Do you know about `urlencode` and `urldecode` features in any programming language which converts non-alpha-numeric characters to a string just like a blank space ' ' to '%20'. Another example 'ferret john' to ferret%20john. I want to decode Url in dart / flutter. Any suggestion, please share. Thanks.

Comment: I have already used `uri.decodeFull()` function to get decoded URL but it does not work in my case as mentioned in question. If I use it then it returns an error in console eg. `Illegal percent encoding in URI`

Comment: Where exactly "it" doesn't work? Want to share minimal reproducible example? I just tried Uri.decodeFull(str) and it produces exactly the result as what you have in your second block.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you'd like to apply HTML tags to display hyperlinks on Widgets? You can use a package like [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/) to display HTML code.

```dart
String htmlData = 'Please use this link to see Ferret John profile <a href="http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret john" target="_blank">http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret john</a> and like it.';

...

Html(
  data: htmlData,
)
```