# Question about dynamic links in Unity iOS

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using dynamic links in Unity iOS.
All settings were carried out and coded according to the manual.
It works without any problems on Android, but problems are occurring on iOS.
When I click the link, the app runs, but the dynamic link-related callback is not being called.

The XCode log displays the following.

```
2021-11-27 13:34:30.312774+0800 ProductName[1370:320855] 8.6.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    amv = 3;
    apn = "net.fineseed.vspe";
    ibi = "net.fineseed.vspe";
    imv = 0;
    isi = 1568434693;
    link = "https://v-spe.com/?screen_id=register?time=1637913115?uid=116";
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could cooperate with me on what the problem is.

I look forward to your kind cooperation.
Thank you.

- Unity 2020.3.3 (iOS)
- XCode 13
- Firebase 8.6.2

Comment: Your question looks similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294267/deep-link-does-not-contain-valid-required-params-while-clicking-a-dynamic-link Does this help? I found a few results Googling "Xcode Deep Link does not contain valid required params"